# NodeJS customize command issues

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm create the custom command `"start:dev":"tsc -p . && copy -R '.\\public' '.\\dist\\public' && node '.\\dist\\app.js'"`  and `"debug":"set DEBUG=* && npm run start:dev"` in package.json file on windows. But when I run the command "npm run debug" will come out the error message  "The system cannot find the file specified". I'm checked the path all are correct. why this error occur ?